# Why am I getting blank plots but no error messages?

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method

I am trying to create two density plots of values but one plot has blank spots and the other is entirely blank. I do not get any errors when I run the code so I am not sure why the plots are turning out like this. Below is my code. I've separated it into 3 sections; defining constants that will be used in proceeding calculations and creating the mesh, solving a differential equation using NDSolve, and using the results of NDSolve to solve for the values I want to plot. Throughout the domain, the value of sige is a function of mu and sigi is constant except in two sections of the right boundary. There is a discontinuity in sige and sigi at the boundary, so to account for this I have created a very small transition region next to the boundary where sigi and sige linearly transition from their values within the domain to the values at the boundary. This is the purpose of the Piecewise functions in the third section.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* 1) Define Constants and create mesh*)
e = 1.60217662*10^-19;
sigi0 = 18; 
sigini = 0;
sigeni = 1.5*10^7;
T = 1000; 
R = 8.314; 
kb = 1.381*10^-23; 
mu2 = -5.984*^-19;
l = 10*10^-6;
y1 = 0.01; 
y2 = 0.0025; 
y3 = 0.005; 
y4 = 0.006; 
y5 = 0.007; 
pts = {{0, 0}, {l, 0}, {l, y2}, {l, y3}, {l, y4}, {l, y5}, {l, 
    y1}, {0, y1}, {0, y5}, {0, y4}, {0, y3}, {0, y2}};
incidents = Partition[FindShortestTour[pts][[2]], 2, 1];
markers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7};
bcEle = {LineElement[incidents, markers]};
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> pts, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> bcEle];
mrf = With[{rmf = 
     RegionMember[
      Region@RegionUnion[Disk[{l, y2}, 0.0025], Disk[{l, y3}, 0.0025],
         Disk[{l, y4}, 0.0025], Disk[{l, y5}, 0.0025]]]}, 
   Function[{vertices, area}, Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices];
     Which[rmf[{x, y}], 
      area > (2.5*10^-10)/258, (x > 0.9*l) && (y2*0.9 <= y <= y3*1.1),
       area > 2.5*10^-10, (x > 0.9*l) && (y4*0.9 <= y <= y5*1.1), 
      area > 2.5*10^-10, True, area > 2.5*10^-7]]]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MeshRefinementFunction -> mrf];

(* 2) Solve for mu profile*)
mu1 = 0;
bcmu = {DirichletCondition[mu[x, y] == mu1, (x == 0 && 0 < y < y1)], 
   DirichletCondition[
    mu[x, y] == 
     mu2, (x == l && y2 < y < y3) || (x == l && y4 < y < y5)]};
solmu = NDSolve[{Laplacian[mu[x, y], {x, y}] == 
     0 + NeumannValue[0, 
       y == 0 || 
        y == y1 || (x == l && 0 <= y <= y2) || (x == l && 
          y3 <= y <= y4) || (x == l && y5 <= y <= y1)], bcmu}, 
   mu, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]; 

(* 3) Solve for sigi and sige everywhere and plot results*)
pO2data = Exp[(mu[x, y] /. solmu)/kb/T];
sige0 = 2.77*10^-7;
sigedata = 
  Piecewise[{{sige0*pO2data^(-1/4), 
     0 <= x <= 
      0.99999*l}, {(sigeni - 
          sige0*(pO2data /. x -> 0.99999*l)^(-1/4))/(0.99999*l)*x + 
      sige0*(pO2data /. x -> 0.99999*l)^(-1/4), 0.99999*l < x <= l}}];
sigidata = 
  Piecewise[{{sigi0, 
     0 <= x <= 0.99999*l}, {(sigini - sigi0)/(0.99999*l)*x + 
      sigi0, (0.99999*l < x <= l && 
       y2 <=  y <= y3)}, {(sigini - sigi0)/(0.99999*l)*x + 
      sigi0, (0.99999*l < x <= l && 
       y4 <= y <= y5)}, {sigi0, (0.99999*l < x <= l && 
       0 <= y < y2)}, {sigi0, (0.99999*l < x <= l && 
       y3 < y < y4)}, {sigi0, (0.99999*l < x <= l && y5 < y <= y1)}}];
DensityPlot[sigedata, {x, 0, l}, {y, 0, y1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Sige Results"]
DensityPlot[sigidata, {x, 0, l}, {y, 0, y1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotLabel -> "Sigi Results"]
```

This is what the resulting plots look like:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening or have suggested edits to my code to improve the image resolution? Thanks!

*Update: the suggested edits in the comments fixed the blank plot issue with sigi and improved the resolution of both plots so the last two lines of the code are

```
DensityPlot[sigedata, {x, 0, l}, {y, 0, y1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Sige Results", 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
DensityPlot[sigidata, {x, 0, l}, {y, 0, y1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotLabel -> "Sigi Results", Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

and the plots look like this

[image]
[image]

The plot of sige still has blank spots, and I am not sure why. I know there should be values where the blank spots are because if I plot a slice of the sigedata at x=8*10^-6

```
Plot[sigedata /. x -> 8*10^-6, {y, 0, y1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Sige Results at x = 8*10^-6", 
 AxesLabel -> {"y-Position", "sige"}]
```

this is the result

[image]

Why isn't the DensityPlot for sige showing these values? I added `Exclusions->None` to the function but it is still excluding values.

Comment: `Table[sigidata, {y, 0, y1, y1/30}, {x, 0, l, l/30}] // MatrixPlot` your data is almost all 18 over the ranges for  y1 and l. If you add `Exclusions -> None` to your `DensityPlot` then you'll see it.

Comment: @flinty thanks for your help! Do you know how to fix the white patches in the sige plot? I added Exclusions -> None to that DensityPlot as well but it didn't help

Comment: Maybe DensityPlot the Log of sige instead. The resolution could be improved with `PlotPoints -> 50`.

Answer (score 2):

After doing further research into the options for `DensityPlot` I was able to answer my own question. Adding a Log scale to the function with `ScalingFunctions-> "Log"` produces a full plot of all sige values

```
DensityPlot[sigedata, {x, 0, l}, {y, 0, y1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Sige Results", 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]